# Mulitple URL pattern for same end point in jax-ws

Tags: xml, soap, wsdl, jax-ws

I have a web service based on Jax-ws.The requirement is providing multiple url pattern for a single endpoint in sun-jaxws.xml.Please see the below xml to get a clear view.

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<endpoints
  xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jax-ws/ri/runtime"
  version="2.0">
  <endpoint name="sample" implementation="com.test.Service" 
   url-pattern="/sample/123/request"/>
  <endpoint name="sample" implementation="com.test.Service" 
   url-pattern="/sample/234/request"/>
</endpoints>
```

In this XML file i created two endpoint to the same implementation class(com.test.Service). Now it is allowing me to create wsdl for the both URLS.While creating wsdl for the second URL(/sample/234/request?wsdl) it is creating wsdl file properly.

see the below wsdl file

```html
<import namespace="https://paysecure/merchant.soap/" location="/sample/234/request?wsdl=1"/>
```

But the problem is if i try to create wsdl for the first URL(/sample/123/request?wsdl) it is creating the same wsdl file
created by the second URL.

created wsdl by First URL:

```html
<import namespace="https://paysecure/merchant.soap/" location="/sample/234/request?wsdl=1"/>
```

Here the location is not changed to "/sample/123/request?wsdl=1". So whenever if i try to create any client with this wsdl file.It will point to the second URL only.

So how can i solve this?Please help me

Comment: Please remove code snippets and use standard Code.

Answer (score 1):

Try making the values of the `name` attribute unique:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<endpoints xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jax-ws/ri/runtime" version="2.0">
  <endpoint name="sample" implementation="com.test.Service" url-pattern="/sample/123/request"/>
  <endpoint name="sample2" implementation="com.test.Service" url-pattern="/sample/234/request"/>
</endpoints>
```